# VR Box Bluetooth Remote Driver Error in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, remote-control

I'm working on a project that requires a small wireless device that can trigger events in a Unity application I'm writing for PC, and I settled on a VR Box Bluetooth Remote. I originally found the device listed on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-Gamepad-Remote-Controller-For-VR-BOX-PC-Phones-Android-IOS/122240945362?_trksid=p2047675.c100010.m2109&_trkparms=aid%3D2220072%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D40130%26meid%3Dbffde9ab84e94420bdb3a70d96613a38%26pid%3D100010%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D112197855819) where it says it's compatible with PC, but due to my companies policies I wasn't allowed to buy it from there and ended up buying it bundled with a VR headset from [Umart](http://www.umart.com.au/newsite/goods.php?id=35328). The Umart page only says "Compatible with iOS and Android", but I assumed that refers to the headset itself which doesn't make sense to list PC. As far as I can tell the bluetooth remote is the same as the ebay one.

Edit: the instructions slip that came with the remote says it supports PC.

I'm able to use the remote with my Android phone without any problems, but when I pair it with my PC it pairs, tries to install a driver, and then Windows (win 10 x64) just says "Driver Error" and the device doesn't work at all.

It shows up in device manager under Bluetooth as "VR BOX" which says it's working properly and under Human Interface Devices as "Bluetooth Low Energy GATT compliant HID device" with an exclamation mark icon and the device status:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
```

Does anyone have any ideas I could try to get it working?

---

If I can't get it working I'll need to find and buy another controller of some sort. It needs to be something small with a few buttons (~6 would be ideal) which I can use to trigger events in my Unity application. Any suggestions would be most welcome.